# Can create procedure without using delimiter in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, delimiter

I have a question about creating stored procedure in MySql without using delimiter
I search a lot in web but i dont find anything usefull for finding my answer.
so can we ever dont use delimiter??
if yes, how?
I am so happy if anyone can help me here with this question
thank you

Comment: As far as I know, only single statement procs can avoid the need for delimiter changes.

Comment: I think you can create a stored procedure that is a single statement.  Doesn't sound very useful, but I think it is possible.

Comment: @Uueerdo Thanks man, can you give me an example?

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you too sir, can you give me an example?

Answer (score 7):

If the procedure is just a single statement, you don't need to change the delimiter.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE myProc(param INT)
SELECT col1, col2 FROM someTable WHERE col3 = param;
```

You only have to change the delimiter if the procedure consists of multiple statements, since `;` is the statement terminator in the procedure. If you don't change the delimiter, it will be treated as the terminator of the `CREATE PROCEDURE` statement itself.